# Automatically update iPhone app database without making user do anything

Tags: ios, database, auto-update

I have a pretty strong background in C++ and am making the switch to Objective-C to try to make an iPhone app. A main component of my app will be a database.

1) Is there a way to update the database of the app without requiring users to update to a new version from the App Store?

2) If there is, where & how do you pull the data into your app? Do you have to pull it from a website?

2a) Is there a way to make a master copy of the app that I can make data changes in and then have that copy update all other versions of the app?

---

If my database contains info that is only updated by me, do I need to store each piece of data as an object?

Ex: One "object" may have a name, a type, a number, and a picture

names, and types will overlap but numbers and pictures will be unique

Thanks again.

Comment: By "update the database" do you mean the schema or the data?

Comment: Sorry, the data. More than likely the only thing that will change will be the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, copy the datdabase (SQLite) from the application bundle to the documents folder. For an update, download over top the old one. Also, you can use something simpler than a database like an `NSDictionary` stored in a .plist file.
2. Yes, from a web server. `NSDictionary` has methods that let you download directly from a URL (`dictionaryWithContentsOfURL`). So does `NSData`.
3. Why not use third party tools to edit data? You can store a `NSDictionary` in a .plist file and edit it there, then upload it to the web server.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Do you think you could elaborate on point number 3 as I am new to this whole iPhone app field. Thanks again.

Comment: @ScottMongiardo, XCode has a built-in .plist file editor. You can also edit them with a text editor (they look similar to XML). For a SQLite database, you'll use the standard client or some off-the-shelf client.

Comment: Gotcha. So just to clarify, the only way to update data in the app is through a web server?

Comment: @ScottMongiardo, or an app update (through the App Store) by updating the application bundle.